# GDAL raster calculator

Tags: qgis, gdal, raster-calculator, syntax

I have a series of raster data (GeoTIFF) with 5 bands (B / G / R / rededge / NIR).

I would like to calculate different indices by using the gdal raster calculator. I would like to use the batch process at the end.

I don't know what to do, because I can't set the GDAL raster calculator to produce reasonable results.

What's wrong with the following syntax settings: [image]

Comment: Does your raster contain no_data values? This was a problem up until recent QGIS versions (see https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/32025). Could you maybe show/tell us what are the "unreasonable" results you get? Note also that the QGIS raster calculator is different from the GDAL raster calculator (which you can also find in the processing toolbox).

Answer (score 2):

You can try to write the code like below:
`gdal_calc.py -A input.tif --A_band=1 -B input.tif --B_band=2 -C input.tif --C_band=3 -D input.tif --D_band=4 --outfile=output.tif --calc="((A-B)/(C+D))"`